# Is there any solution to performing the same/similar database action by multiple threads at the exact-ish same time?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Using Java, Spring Boot, and Hibernate, is there any way to allow a given action to be performed at the same time by multiple threads, without causing a deadlock or stale data exception.

For example, suppose an automated tool is logging in twice at the same time, and this causes one of the following:

1. A deadlock because the user record is being updated by both threads (requests) at the same time, for instance to store the user's last logged in date/time.
2. A stale data exception because one thread updates the user just before the other thread's transaction is completed.

This can be solved by adding synchronization on the user's id, but this sort of thing would have to be done *everywhere*, leading a potential performance hit, and making the code base more bloated and hard to follow.

Alternatively, we could adjust the isolation level (perhaps we can set the default level globally). Is this a better solution, or is there another solution?

Comment: RDBMS are [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) compliant so they are built to handle concurrent updates to the same data. What DB transaction strategy are you using?

Comment: In most cases, we're using the default for MySQL, which is `REPEATABLE READ`. The issue is that Hibernate (correctly) won't update a record whose version is less than what it sees in its local copy of the entity.

Comment: IMHO requiring repeatable read indicates a broken application design, and it's costly for the DB. Redesign your application to not need it and use the isolation level that's the most relaxed you can get away with

Answer (score 2):

**Pessimistic locking.**

As early as possible in your transaction, lock all the rows you may need to update. You can do this with a [locking read](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html).

```
SELECT ... FROM Users WHERE user_id = ? FOR UPDATE;
```

Only one thread will acquire it. The others will wait for that thread to release the lock.

In the meantime, the thread that holds the lock can UPDATE the row when it is ready.

```
UPDATE Users SET last_login = NOW() WHERE user_id = ?;
```

Then to be courteous to the other threads, commit as promptly as possible after the `UPDATE`. This automatically releases the lock(s).

```
COMMIT;
```

This allows the next queued thread to acquire the lock it was waiting for.

You can use the locking read to lock multiple rows, even from multiple tables. Any rows examined by the `SELECT` query will become locked. You can do JOINs and so on if you need to lock rows from multiple tables.

Lock acquisition is atomic, so a given locking statement must acquire *all* the requested locks, or else it must wait.

Comment: Make sure that you are aware of the locking granularity of whichever DB you use. e.g. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking.html